# making specific value as default in a parameter ssrs(rdl)

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, rdlc, rdl, ssrs-2017

iam using visual studio 2017 and make an rdl report

and i have a  parameter (drop down)that takes it's values from the query

```
select column1 from table1
```

suppose that there are five elements A,B,C,D,E in column1 of table1

how to  set first value which appears form available values 
to be selected as default in order to not obligate the user to select a value

i mean i don't want to see the phrase    instead i want first value to be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single select values this is the default behaviour.

For multi select you can create another dataset  using TOP and set it as the dataset for the parameter default values

```
select TOP(1) column1 from table1
```

[image]

Comment: can you give any link which talks about using query  of data set as default value  please

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-change-or-delete-default-values-for-a-report-parameter?view=sql-server-2017